# mText1.getLayoutParams().height = NEW VALUE does not take effect in popup window

Tags: android, android-popupwindow, android-layoutparams

In `Android` application,
I create a **LinearLayout** which contains a **TableLayout** which contains some rows and one of the rows contains a **TextView** called **mText1**

I set up a pop up window with this **LinearLayout** with **mText1** setting as following :
`mText1.getLayoutParams().height = OLD VALUE`

Then when in the pop up window in one other row of the table a click on an **ImageView** happens by the user,  I'd like to change the height of **mText1** as following :
`mText1.getLayoutParams().height = NEW VALUE`

The problem is this will not take effect but when I type the following code, it takes effect:
`mText1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)`

Or if I type the following code instead of the previous one, it takes effect too:
`mText1.setText("some value")`

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `requestLayout()` after changing the `LayoutParams`.

> [requestLayout()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestLayout())
>
> Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout
>   of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.

`setGravity` and `setText` are handling this for you.